# Merge Route::group domain Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

My project need new mirrors domain each weeks only for the API.
To do that, in the route file I add a `Route::group` for each domains.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'domain2.com'], function(){
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api', 'prefix' => 'r'], function() {
        Route::get('/{hash}', 'ApiController@index');
    });
    Route::get('/', function(){
        return view('errors.noshort');
    });
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'domain1.com'], function(){
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api', 'prefix' => 'r'], function() {
        Route::get('/{hash}', 'ApiController@index');
    });
    Route::get('/', function(){
        return view('errors.noshort');
    });
});
```

1. How can I merge this two `Route::group` and the next ?
2. Can I get all the domains from my database to dynamically do the route ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly you can not assign array to `domain`. It expects only single string parameters.

You can do like this. to assign `Route::group` store in your DB  fetch it in your `route` file

Try this hope it helps.

like,

```
$domains = \App\Domain::all();

foreach ($domains as $domain) {
    Route::group(['domain' => $domain->domainName], function(){
        Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api', 'prefix' => 'r'], function() {
        Route::get('/{hash}', 'ApiController@index');
        });
        Route::get('/', function(){
        return view('errors.noshort');
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 link your domains like this:

```
$apiRoutes = function() {
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api', 'prefix' => 'r'], function() {
        Route::get('/{hash}', 'ApiController@index');
    });
    Route::get('/', function(){
        return view('errors.noshort');
    });
};

Route::group(['domain' => 'domain2.com'], $apiRoutes);
Route::group(['domain' => 'domain1.com'], $apiRoutes);
```

2 Difficult to understand what you mean by import your domains